# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST when I am installing wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress, fatal-error

Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST when I am installing wordpress theme

PHP Version     5.4.41

Getting following error : - 
Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in /public_html/linuxnlinux.com/wp-content/themes/Answers_v1.2/Answers/library/functions/custom_functions.php on line 1360

Code at line 1360 is : -

```
}

function get_user_name($uid)
{
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var("select display_name from $wpdb->users where ID=\"$uid\"");
}

function veryfy_login_and_proced($_POST,$redirecturl = '')   // 1360 line
{
    $secure_cookie = '';
    if ( !empty($_POST['log']) && !force_ssl_admin() ) {
        $user_name = sanitize_user($_POST['log']);
        if ( $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_name) ) {
            if ( get_user_option('use_ssl', $user->ID) ) {
                $secure_cookie = true;
                force_ssl_admin(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Superglobals are not allowed to be used as parameters to a function since PHP 5.4 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php#112184

So your function needs to look like this: 
`function veryfy_login_and_proced()   // 1360 line`

You can then pass your parameters inside the function. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: You can as well check Wordpress Codex [link](http://codex.wordpress.org) for more information about wordpress-theming

Comment: Glad to help! Can you mark the question as answered?